# A recursive function to print the prime factoring element of an integer

Tags: c++, recursion

I need to write a recursive function to print the prime factoring elements of an integer, ascending.

```
void printPrimeFactors(int num)
{
int div;

if (isPrime(num) == true)
    cout << num << " ";

else
{
    for (div = 2; div < num; div++)
    {
        if (isPrime(div) == true && num%div == 0)
            printPrimeFactors(num/div);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? My output, for 20 is:

```
5 2 5 2 2
```

My smallest input is a prime number and a smaller input for the recursive function is `num div (smallest prime divider of num)`.

Comment: What do you see that makes you think you do something wrong?

Comment: my output, for 20 it's: 5 2 5 2 2

Comment: Edited that into your question.

Comment: You shouldn't be looping *and* recurring.

Comment: how else can I find the smallest prime number that divides num?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the following will work:

```
void printPrimeFactors(int num, int div = 2)
{
        if (num % div == 0) {
                std::cout << div << " ";
                printPrimeFactors(num / div, div);
        } else if (div <= num) {
                printPrimeFactors(num, div + 1);
        }
}
```

As requested, it is recursive, even though recursion isn't necessary and can be trivially converted into iteration.

The reason your original version doesn't quite work is twofold:

1. the printing is misplaced, which results in the factors being printed in descending order;
2. after the recursive call you keep trying further divisors, which results in the duplicate factors appearing on the output.

Comment: There's no need for `isPrime(div)`. If `div` isn't prime, then some number `x` where `2 <= x < div` would have been called before it.

Comment: As it is a part of my homework for college, I am not allowed to `break;` a loop while it's working.

Comment: @sharth It short circuits the check on `num % div == 0`, though.  It's seems unlikely that there's actually a performance benefit from it, of course, but just to play devil's advocate.

Comment: @sharth: That's a good point, thanks. I've completely redone the solution. I believe the new one to be a lot better (and correct!)

Comment: @femtoRgon: I can't imagine that `isPrime(div)` has anywhere near the cost of `num % div`. `isPrime` will be orders of magnitude more expensive.

Comment: @NPE: Add a base case to your recursion. `if (num == 1) return;`

Comment: @sharth: Is that necessary? That's what the code already does, since `num == 1` will result in both conditions always evaluating to `false`.

Comment: @NPE: Oops. You're correct. I assumed the second case was just an else.

Answer (score 1):

NPE has provided a (tail) recursive version, here's the iterative version:

What we do here is:

1. Our first possible divisor is 2. Try that value.
2. If it divides the number evenly, then print the divisor, and divide our target number by that divisor.
3. If it doesn't divide, then try the next divisor. `div += 1`.

Note that we don't increment `div` when it does divide. This is because of cases like `20`, where `2` divides it multiple times.

```
void printPrimeFactors(int num) {
    int div = 2;

    while (num != 1) {
        if (num % div == 0) {
            cout << num << " ";
            num /= div;
        } else {
            div += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate, but I am supposed to write a recursive function.